# C# Task.Start() does not work on Release build

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I have a program which runs a method throw multiple tasks like this

```
private static readonly Task[] Tasks = new Task[Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfTasksToConsume];
public static void StartService()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        Tasks[i] = new Task(() => ProcessAbonents(Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfRecordsToRetrive));
        Tasks[i].Start();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(Tasks);

    Task.Run(() => DeleteAbonents((int)EnumCategories.Social));

    if (BadPhoneNumbers.Count > 0)
        Task.Run(() => SaveBadNumbers((int)EnumCategories.Social));

    if (Errors.Count > 0)
        Task.Run(() => SendEmail());
}
```

It works and enters in "ProcessAbonents" method when the program build is in Debug mode but when build is in Release mode the for loop is working fine, but it doesn't enter in this method.

Comment: Please clean and rebuild and check your findings. maybe use some logging. This doesn't make sense with the code you have provided

Comment: Do u wait for the tasks somewhere? Maybe the program ends before the tasks could started?

Comment: @plainionist No inside the loop there is the call of method ProcessAbonents but it doesn't enter inside this method only on Release build. Debug build works fine.

Comment: Could is be that `Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfTasksToConsume` is set differently for Debug and Release?

Comment: @ShayYizhak No, it is the same on both build.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question directly but why are you using `Task.Start` instead of `Task.Run`? `Task.Run` also returns the `Task`.

Comment: @llian Pinzon I tried Task.Run() but the same result.

Comment: What makes you think that `ProcessAbonents` isn't called?

Comment: @KevinGosse I am logging text inside this method and there is no log file on release, but on debug is. I have two logs, one before calling this method(which works) and another in the beginning of the method body(which does not work).

Comment: Can u pls post ProcessAbonements method as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. There was Oracle.DataAccess.dll x64 and my project was on Any CPU, on Debug it worked fine but on Release maybe it was on x86. When I changed my project to x64 build now it works fine on Release too.